# javascript wildcard in function invocation

Tags: javascript

if I'm invoking the following functions on page load:

```
addOnload(checkHeaders_m1)
addOnload(checkHeaders_m2)
addOnload(checkHeaders_m3)
addOnload(checkHeaders_m4)
addOnload(checkHeaders_m5)
```

can I save myself some code by using a wildcard? something like:

```
addOnload(checkHeaders_m\*)
```

Comment: The answer has been deleted, but it's worth noting that, architecturally, this is probably a bad setup and could be simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your onload functions are global then they would exist on the `window` object:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    addOnload(window['checkHeaders_m' + i]);
}
```

Alternatively, make the functions properties of some other object so that you [don't pollute the global namespace](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#namespace):

```
var myObj = {
    checkHeaders_m1: function () { ... },
    checkHeaders_m2: function () { ... },
    checkHeaders_m3: function () { ... },
    checkHeaders_m4: function () { ... },
    checkHeaders_m5: function () { ... }
};

for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    addOnload(myObj['checkHeaders_m' + i]);
}
```

Comment: I learn more on Stack in 3 minutes than I could in an hour elsewhere. Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could always use an array. But you'd still have to make multiple function calls - at least with an array you can write a loop instead of manually typing those calls.

Answer (score 0):

What are `checkHeaders_m1...`?
This looks like an ideal candidate for an array.

```
for(var i=0; i<checkHeaders_m.length; i++)
{
addOnload(checkHeaders_m[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Array.map`?

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(a){addOnload(window['checkHeaders_m'+a]); return a;});
```

Where `window` may be some other namespace ofcourse

Or

```
[checkHeaders_m1,checkHeaders_m2,checkHeaders_m3,checkHeaders_m4,checkHeaders_m5]
 .map(function(ch){addOnload(ch);return ch;});
```